# In VBA how do I get around the error: "Duplicate Declaration in Current Scope" If I want my code to certain tasks (if/else) depending on checkboxes

Tags: excel, vba

Here I just want it so that if another checkbox is clicked, it'll run the code in the Else block. The code will run just fine, with just the If Choice1 is True block but I'll get a `Duplicate Declaration in Current Scope` error when I add the Else blocks:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    If Choice1.Value = True Then
    

        Dim filename As String
        filename = ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & "somefile.xlsm"
    
        Dim wk As Workbook
        Set wk = Workbooks.Open(filename, ReadOnly:=True)
    
        Dim rgSource As Range, rgDestination As Range
    
        ' set rgsource = [workbook].[worksheet].[range]
        Set rgSource = ThisWorkbook**strong text**.Worksheets("Source").**Range("A1:B7")**
        Set rgDestination = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Destination").Range("A1")
    
        rgSource.Copy
        rgDestination.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    
        wk.Close saveChanges:=False
        
    ElseIf Choice2.Value = True Then

        Dim filename As String
        filename = ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & "Otherfile.xlsm"

        Dim wk As Workbook
        Set wk = Workbooks.Open(filename, ReadOnly:=True)

        Dim rgSource As Range, rgDestination As Range

        ' set rgsource = [workbook].[worksheet].[range]
        Set rgSource = wk.Worksheets("Sheet1").**Range("E1:F7")**
        Set rgDestination = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Destination").Range("A1")

        rgSource.Copy
        rgDestination.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

        wk.Close saveChanges:=False

    ElseIf Choice3.Value = True Then ...etc.

    
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You have declared few variable twice like `filename`, `wk`. So, remove few and just keep one variable.

Comment: As @Harun24HR said. Put the single variable before the start of the `If` statement.

Comment: That worked! Thank you @ Harun24HR and @ Darren Bartrup-Cook

Comment: Another question, if you guys are up for it: 
Instead of a check box I tried using a Combobox - I do: 

If ComboBox1.Value = "some_string" Then
do the same process as the example

I do not get the same result. Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

Declare all variables at starting of code. You can declare anywhere but it is good practice to declare variables first. Try below sub.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim filename As String
Dim wk As Workbook
Dim rgSource As Range, rgDestination As Range
    
    If Choice1.Value = True Then
            filename = ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & "somefile.xlsm"
        Set wk = Workbooks.Open(filename, ReadOnly:=True)
        ' set rgsource = [workbook].[worksheet].[range]
        Set rgSource = ThisWorkboo.Worksheets("Source").Range("A1:B7")
        Set rgDestination = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Destination").Range("A1")
            rgSource.Copy
            rgDestination.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            wk.Close saveChanges:=False
    ElseIf Choice2.Value = True Then
            filename = ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & "Otherfile.xlsm"
        Set wk = Workbooks.Open(filename, ReadOnly:=True)
        ' set rgsource = [workbook].[worksheet].[range]
        Set rgSource = wk.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E1:F7")
        Set rgDestination = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Destination").Range("A1")
            rgSource.Copy
            rgDestination.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            wk.Close saveChanges:=False
    ElseIf Choice3.Value = True Then
        DoEvents
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Another thing is when you set any object then always `set object=nothing` to clear memory when tasks are finished to avoid unexpected behavior of code.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to declare the variable once so you can just place it above like this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    
    Dim filename As String
    Dim wk As Workbook
    Dim rgSource As Range, rgDestination As Range
    
    If Choice1.Value = True Then
            
        filename = ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & "somefile.xlsm"
        
        Set wk = Workbooks.Open(filename, ReadOnly:=True)
    
        ' set rgsource = [workbook].[worksheet].[range]
        Set rgSource = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Source").Range("A1:B7")
        Set rgDestination = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Destination").Range("A1")
    
        rgSource.Copy
        rgDestination.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    
        wk.Close saveChanges:=False
        
    ElseIf Choice2.Value = True Then
            
        filename = ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & "Otherfile.xlsm"
    
        Set wk = Workbooks.Open(filename, ReadOnly:=True)

        ' set rgsource = [workbook].[worksheet].[range]
        Set rgSource = wk.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E1:F7")
        Set rgDestination = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Destination").Range("A1")

        rgSource.Copy
        rgDestination.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

        wk.Close saveChanges:=False

    ElseIf Choice3.Value = True Then ...etc.

    
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: When you copy paste codes then must notice is there any extra texts. Your codes will fail because it has some extra texts those will not be compiled like `ThisWorkbook**strong text**.Worksheets("Source").**Range("A1:B7")**` Here `**strong text**` are not any `VBA` language codes for this line.

Comment: Sorry, I just made some of those bold to highlight that I was only making small changes to the range but the rest of the code is identical. So the "*" isn't actually in my code :)

Comment: My bad, didn't even notice there are **strong text** when I copy/paste it. Have edited it.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not use `Option Explicit` you can safely omit declarations and get rid of problems :)

But it is not good practice and is just an alternative to other answers.